# Keyboard stops working, can't login from locked screen window

Tags: keyboard, 14.04

I left my PC and when I returned the screen was locked. I can move the mouse and see the whole screen, but I can't type.  This seemed to happen randomly, and only a hard reset helps in this case.

Please help!